# how to match a field name with another field name

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

I have two fields that run throughout a website that I would like to match so that when a user inputs a value either of the fields, it will match the other field. I'm using Sitecore Rocks and am trying to use a query to do this.

```
 select @#h1#, @#Title#
 from /sitecore/Content/Home//*[@#h1# !="@#Title#"];

 update set @#h1# = @#Title# from /sitecore/Content/Home//*[@#Title# = "<id>"];
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Silly question maybe. But why have 2 fields at all?

Comment: This is the way the system was built using these two fields.

Answer (score 1):

This article talks about tapping in to the `item:saving` event which allows you to compare the fields values of the item before and after the changes:

http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Intercepting-Item-Updates-with-Sitecore.aspx

Using this, you can determine which field has been amended, then change the other to match.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar to this when a new field was added, and we wanted to set the initial value equal to an existing field.  It may be a bug in Sitecore Rocks, but I found it would only update a field when a static value was part of the query.

When I ran `@#h1# = @#Title#`, the query analyzer would return the correct number of items updated, but no values were actually updated. However, `@#h1# = '<id>'` worked perfectly. After trying a number of things, I found this did what I wanted.

```
update set @#h1# = '' + @#Title# from /sitecore/Content/Home//*[@#Title# = "<id>"];
```

I hope that helps.